# php download file from database on button press

Tags: php, download

I am trying to trigger the download of a file from my database using a button.

I have used the following code to upload a file to my database:

```
$loanform = $_FILES['loanform']['name'];
$uploadfile = "loanforms/$loanform";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['loanform']['tmp_name'],$uploadfile);
```

The database stores the filename and the actual file is stored within the *loanforms* directory on the webserver.

When I then click to view a specific user's records all their data from my database is displayed with a button to download the file. However when the button is clicked nothing happens.

To get the user's info I use the following code;

```
$loanid=$_GET['loanid']; 

$my_query="select * from loans where loanid=$loanid";
$result= mysqli_query($connection, $my_query);

while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):

    $username = $myrow["username"];
    $emailaddress = $myrow["emailaddress"];
    $product = $myrow["product"];
    $product_desc = $myrow["product_desc"];
    $serial = $myrow["serial"];
    $date_collected=$myrow["date_collected"];
    $date_return=$myrow["date_return"];
    $loanform=$myrow["loanform"];
    $returned=$myrow["returned"];

endwhile;   

if (file_exists($loanform)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($loanform).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($loanform);
        exit;
    }
```

The HTML for the button is:

```
<label class="labelform">Loan Form:</label><input class="inputtextlarge" type="button" name="loanform" autocomplete="off" size="30" value="Download Loan Form">
```

Basically for *loanid=1* the filename stored is *loanform.pdf*. How can I adjust my code for the button to trigger the download of the file?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "nothing happens"?  Is no HTTP request made at all?  If not, is this button in a form at all?  What is handling the button's click event?  If a request is made, how does it fail?  Is the query string value present?  Does the database query fail in some way?  Something else?

Comment: **your code is easy to exploit**. 1. SQL injections are A Very Bad Thing: *?loanid=1 or drop table loans*, 2. I could upload a php file and run whatever I want on your server. 3. Game over. Don't let a user declare the filename and use prepared statements if you don't know how to avoid those SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

Your button does nothing because it's just button. Make it to link:

```
<label class="labelform">
    Loan Form:
</label>
<a href="getLaon.php?loanid=<?= $loanId; ?>" class="inputtextlarge">Download Loan Form</a>
```

---

Also take a note of comments about security under your question.